# How do you create regular expression based rules in Outlook 2010?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, microsoft-outlook-2010, regex

Is it possible to create Regex-based email rules in Outlook 2010? There are certain emails that I would like to automatically sort to a separate folder. They tend to follow a format like this:

```
201702231249_[Product Name]_7.1.6.24
```

If it *is* possible to do in Outlook, how do you do so?

Comment: AFAIK, this is not possible with Outlook's standard rule processing engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No way unless you're going to use the VBA macros (you can fire them from Outlook rules as well).

Comment: How to select VBA macros while selecting the Rules ?